# How the nested loop with some string works in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want the output as shown below:

```
The website is google number 1
The website is facebook number 2
The website is yahoo number 3
```

Where 'google facebook yahoo' are from the list and numbers should be incremented from 1 to 3.

I tried the following python code:

```
websites = "google facebook yahoo"
for web in websites.split( ):
    n=0
    while n < 3:
        n=n+1
        print web,n
```

I am getting output as shown below:

```
C:\Users\test\Desktop>python nested_loop_in_python.py
google 1
google 2
google 3
facebook 1
facebook 2
facebook 3
yahoo 1
yahoo 2
yahoo 3

C:\Users\test\Desktop>
```

But I need output like:

```
The website is google number 1
The website is facebook number 2
The website is yahoo number 3
```

Any clue please?

Answer (score 2):

Use `enumerate`

```
for index, site in enumerate(websites.split(),1):
  print(site, index)
```

Answer (score 1):

First replace:

```
print web,n
```

by

```
print ("The website is " + web + " number " + str(n))
```

and second, replace:

```
for web in websites.split():
    n=0
    while n < 3:
        n=n+1
```

by:

```
n=0
for web in websites.split():
    n=n+1
```

You will get the result you expect. To shorten your code and make it more pythonic I recommend you to use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not getting expected output, I am getting following output : C:\Users\test\Desktop>python nested_loop_in_python.py
The website is google number 1
The website is google number 2
The website is google number 3
The website is facebook number 1
The website is facebook number 2
The website is facebook number 3
The website is yahoo number 1
The website is yahoo number 2
The website is yahoo number 3

C:\Users\test\Desktop>

Comment: Have you made the second replacement ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `enumerate` (https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
websites = "google facebook yahoo"
for j, web in enumerate(websites.split(' '), start=1):
    print 'The website is {0} number {1}'.format(web, j)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
websites = "google facebook yahoo"

l = websites.split()

for w, i in zip(l, range(len(l))):
    print 'The website is {0} number {1}'.format(w,i+1)
```

I could avoid using l and implicitly code like this way:
    websites = "google facebook yahoo"

```
for w, i in zip(websites.split(), range(len(websites.split()))):
    print 'The website is {0} number {1}'.format(w,i+1)
```

This will work as well but remember this rule:

> **EXPLICIT IS BETTER THAN IMPLICIT**